# ¿Existe algo parecido a busquedas full Text en laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Pretendo mostrar cualquier fila que contenga al menos una de las palabras buscadas, y en caso de coincidir en varias, que lo ordene de mayor a menor número de coincidencias.

he encontrado información acerca de el comodin Like con laravel, pero se que al usar el comodin Like los resultados devueltos por el buscador pueden ser muy elevados y totalmente irrelevantes.  por eso  ando buscando algo parecido a full Text-
He encontrado tambien algo de Angolia. pero no quiero usar angolia

ya que como mencione pretendo buscar  mostrar cualquier fila que contenga al menos una de las palabras buscadas, y en caso de coincidir en varias, que lo ordene de mayor a menor número de coincidencias.

Así solia hacerlo

```
ALTER TABLE coches ADD FULLTEXT (nombre, descripcion);
```

.

```
SQL="Select nombre, descripcion From coches Where Match(nombre, descripcion) AGAINST ('criterio');"
```

pero en laravel como es posible con Eloquent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

laravel 9.x https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scout

---

Existe algo parecido a búsquedas fullText en laravel?
Respuesta: si (usar SQL directo y crudo) y no (no está soportado).

Cómo es posible con eloquent?:

**1** con una extensión (por ejemplo esta)

https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence

**2** a pelo (raw queries) como lo vienes haciendo.

```
$query->whereRaw("Select nombre, descripcion From coches Where 
Match(nombre, descripcion) AGAINST ('criterio');";
```

el alter lo puedes meter en una migration (tambien raw sql)

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE coches ADD FULLTEXT (nombre, descripcion);";
```

Para "laravelizar" el code y reutilizarlo (sin usar extensiones) te recomiendo el siguiente tutorial:

https://arianacosta.com/php/laravel/tutorial-full-text-search-laravel-5/

Nota: por qué Laravel no soporta fulltext search nativo?

> Taylor Otwell, the creator of Laravel, wants to keep Eloquent as platform-independent as possible. And since Full Text Search is specific to MySQL, it was not included. In his own words: “Full text search is pretty vendor specific and not something that is currently supported by Laravel.”

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/214

traducción libre:

> Taylor Otwell, el creador de Laravel, desea mantener Eloquent tan independiente de las plataformas como sea posible. Y dado que Full Text Search es especifico de MySQL, no fué incluido. En sus propias palabras:“Full text search es bastante especifico de un vendedor/proveedor/fabricante y no es algo que sea actualmente soportado por Laravel.”